# Second Derivative of basic fraction using quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know this is a very basic question but I need some help.

I have to find the second derivative of:

$$\frac{1}{3x^2 + 4}$$

I start by using the Quotient Rule and get the first derivative to be:

$$\frac{-6x}{(3x^2 + 4)^2}$$

This I believe to be correct.
Following that I proceed to find the second derivative in the same manner but I get this as my answer:
$$\frac{(54x^4 + 144x^2 +96) - (-36x^3 + 48x)}{(9x^4 +24x^2 +16)^2}$$

This I believe to be correct just not simplified.  However the answer I need to get is:
$$- \frac{6(4 - 9x^2)}{(3x^2 + 4)^3}$$
I do not know what the best way to approach this would be, should I multiply out the denominator and try to cancel?  Could someone point me in the right direction, I want to solve it myself but I need some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: General advice that is quite useful here:  don't open parentheses (distribute) unless you have a reason to.

Comment: @Jan, look more closely at the denominators.  The OP has expanded certain polynomials; whereas, the second answer has them still factored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first derivative is correct. Now we want to differentiate $\frac{-6x}{(3x^2+4)^2}$. The main thing to remember is **do not "simplify"** unless there is good reason to do so.

The derivative of $\frac{-6x}{(3x^2+4)^2}$ is
$$\frac{(3x^2+4)^2 (-6)-(-6x)(6x)(2)(3x^2+4)}{(3x^2+4)^4}.$$
Cancel a $3x^2+4$, and simplify the top.

**Remark:** I probably would want to take out that ugly $-6$ from the top, which is an invitation to minus sign errors and other errors, and differentiate $\frac{x}{(3x^2+4)^2}$.

Comment: Perfect, you explained it extremely well.  Your advice is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform the quotient rule, it's often easier to *not* multiply everything out until the end, because there are a lot of cases where you can factor things out and cancel, and if you multiply out first, it will be much harder to see that. Your first derivative is indeed correct, but here's what I'd recommend to get the suggested answer for the second derivative:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{-6x}{\left(3x^2 + 4\right)^2}\right) &= \frac{-6\left(3x^2 + 4\right)^2 - (-6x)(2)\left(3x^2 + 4\right)(6x)}{\left(3x^2 + 4\right)^4}\\
&= \frac{6\left(3x^2 + 4\right)\left(-\left(3x^2 + 4\right) + 12x^2\right)}{\left(3x^2 + 4\right)^4}\\
&= \frac{6\left(9x^2 - 4\right)}{\left(3x^2 + 4\right)^3},
\end{align*}
which is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help also it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(-\frac{6x}{(3x^2+4)^2}\right)'=-\frac{6(3x^2+4)^2-72x^2(3x^2+4)}{(3x^2+4)^4}=$$

$$=-\frac{18x^2+24-72x^2}{(3x^2+4)^3}=-\frac{6(-9x^2+4)}{(3x^2+4)^3}$$